# How can I find the value of the virtual page offset, the value of the virtual page number, and others?

Tags: caching, virtual-memory

## Im having trouble understanding the process of finding the virtual page offset, the value of the physical page offset, and the virtual page number

Ive tried looking at various places but I cannot find any examples or formulas for finding the following parameters. Below is an example of a problem, but I have left out the virtual address from the actual problem.

Given a virtual memory system with the following specification:

- The memory is byte addressable.
- Each memory access is to 1-byte word.
- Each virtual address is 16-bit wide.
- Each physical address is 12-bit wide.
- The page size is 32 bytes (25)
- The TLB is 4-way set associative with 16 total entries.
- The L1 data-cache is physically addressed and direct mapped, with a 4 byte line size and 16 total sets.

**If the CPU issues the following virtual address: (some hex number)**

1. What is the virtual page offset?
2. What is the value of the physical page offset?
3. What is the value of the TLB tag?
4. What is the value of the TLB index?
5. What is the value of the virtual page number?
   (Answers in binary)

After turning the hex number to binary, I am lost. How can I find the virtual page offset? Whats the difference between the virtual page offset and the physical page, and how do I find the value of the physical page?

I think the TLB tag is the remaining digits after the VPO and PPO, but I would need to know how to get the VPO and the PPO first. I am unsure what the TLB index is. The VPN is a combination of some of these answers but I am not sure which.

What happens if the set associative is changed to a 2 way TLB? does that change the way I find these values?

Finally, If I were given a 2-way set associative TLB and a page table with the same information above, how can I determine if there is a page fault or not? From what I understand, if there is a TLB hit there is no page fault, but if not, how can I determine this? He also talks about a physical address, what is the process of finding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the virtual page offset?
>   What is the value of the physical page offset?

VPO are addresses of a byte within a page. Concerning physical pages, they are generally called frames, but the offset definition is identical.
`VPO = VAdr %  PageSize`

> What is the value of the TLB tag?
>   What is the value of the TLB index?

TLB index maps a VAdr to a TLB set.
`Number-of-sets = number-of-TLB-entries / number-of-ways`
and `ìndex-size =log_2(number-of-sets)`
TLB tag is the remaining MS bits in virtual address

> What is the value of the virtual page number?

Virtual-page-number = virtual-adresse / page-size

If address is in binary  `abdefghijklmnopq` its interpretation as `(TLBTag,TLBidx,VPO)` is `(abdefghij,kl,mnopq)` and virtual page address is `abdefghijkl`.

> What happens if the set associative is changed to a 2 way TLB? does that change the way I find these values?

If the number of entries is unchanged, this divides the number of sets by 2 and adds one bit to `TLBIdx` (and removes one from `TLBTag`).

> Finally, If I were given a 2-way set associative TLB and a page table with the same information above, how can I determine if there is a page fault or not? From what I understand, if there is a TLB hit there is no page fault, but if not, how can I determine this?

If there is a TLB hit, there is no page fault. If there is a TLB miss, page address has to be generated by looking at process page tables. These tables indicates correspondence between virtual and logical page addresses and if a page is in memory or swapped to disk. If the page is swapped to disk, this is a *page fault*. This generates an exception and the OS has to write the page back to memory.

> He also talks about a physical address, what is the process of finding this?

For simple situations like yours, it can just be a table lookup. A page address is 11 bits wide and a 2048 entry table indicates the address of the corresponding physical frame. In real systems, this is more complex and generally involve several cascading tables.

Comment: So if I am given a page table, and there was a TLB miss, I need to find the VPN and the PPN, and determine if it is a valid bit - and If it is on the page table, It is not a page fault?

Comment: Right. There is in some form a validity bit in the page table. If requested page is present and validity bit is set,  no page fault. Otherwise OS has to process page fault, bring back the page from swap zone to some frame of physical memory and update page table entry.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the virtual page offset?

Address MOD Page Size

> What is the value of the physical page offset?

Address / Page Size

> What is the value of the TLB tag?

Unknown from what you have given.

> What is the value of the TLB index?

Unknown from what you have given.

> What is the value of the virtual page number? (Answers in binary)

Address / Page Size